# How do i change the background color of a div with screens smaller than 200px?

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
<div id="changeBackgroundColor"> content <div>

.changeBackgroundColor{
 background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (width <= 200px){
   .changeBackgroundColor{
      background-color: green;
}
```

it seems to have some syntax error

Comment: Use _@media only screen and (max-width: 200px)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
<div id="changeBackgroundColor"> content <div>

#changeBackgroundColor{
 background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width 200px){
   #changeBackgroundColor{
      background-color: green;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

The correct syntax is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px)
```

and if you use `.` in CSS you're declaring a class. Your div has the `id` field. Either replace `id` with `class`, or `.` with `#`

```css
.changeBackgroundColor {
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .changeBackgroundColor {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="changeBackgroundColor"> content
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.changeBackgroundColor {
  background-color: black;
}

@media (max-width:200px) {
  .changeBackgroundColor {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="changeBackgroundColor">content </div>
```